# Impressora Bluetooth e Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, impressora

Existe alguma api para enviar ordens de impressão através de um app android?
Já vi que a samsung incluiu há algum tempo essa funcionalidade de impressão por bluetooth, mas não consigo achar nada a respeito de enviar ordens de impressão de forma nativa para estes dispositivos.

Alguma luz?

Comment: Coloque o modelo da impressora e dá uma pesquisada, Normalmente quando isso é possível a empresa disponibiliza uma dll para você utilizar.

Comment: Obrigado! Vou me informar!

Comment: Estou enfrentando o mesmo problema que é a impressão em ANDROID - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157558/selecionar-impressora-via-php-no-android?noredirect=1#comment328965_157558. Acompanharei essa pergunta e deixei o link da minha, caso apareça resposta que solucione seu problema.

Comment: Andreson, eu resolvi meu problema assim que estive com a impressora em mãos. A própria fabricante disponibiliza uma api para fazer a interface com a impressora. Só foi necessário implementar o acesso à api e tudo correu perfeitamente.