# Comunicação local através de aplicação on-line

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para pedidos de uma lanchonete/pizzaria. Vamos supor que o garçom faça o pedido com o Tablet (**Android**) na mesa do cliente ou o cliente vai e faz o pedido na recepção (**Windows**). Dependendo o pedido, o mesmo deverá ser impresso em uma **impressora diferente**, por exemplo: caso seja pedido x-salada deverá ser impresso em impressora no "setor" da cozinha correspondente e caso seja pedido uma pizza o mesmo deverá ser impresso em outro "setor" que seja correspondente à pizza.

Alguém poderia me indicar algum artigo, ou os comandos a fim de hora imprimir em uma determinada impressora e hora em outra impressora? Teria que haver uma codificação para cada sistema operacional ou a mesma serviria para ambos?

Obs: as impressoras são todas impressoras térmicas Epson.

---

Farei o teste para o **Windows**, mas no **Android**, como poderia fazer o gerenciamento de impressão? Também seria interessante no **Windows Phone**, pois o foco é atendimento dos garçons com um Tablet com menor custo, independente o sistema operacional.

---

A arquitetura proposta é esta, onde cada Tablet teria as impressoras instaladas e deles saíssem o comando de impressão de acordo com o tipo de pedido. Todas as estações acessariam o sistema via internet (sem servidor dentro do estabelecimento), onde nada em relação ao sistema seria necessário instalar nas estações além das impressoras.

Meu foco é trabalhar com impressões e impressoras via **Android**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Como foi sugerido, e por sinal achei boa sugestão, utilizarei uma outra arquitetura, como mostrada na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A nova dúvida é como posso enviar dados de uma aplicação on-line (utilizando  *Tablet*) para um servidor local?

Em princípio pensei enviar utilizando AJAX por aparentar ser uma solução mais simples, mas até o momento não encontrei referência de como enviar solicitação AJAX para servidor local através de uma aplicação on-line.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54200/discussion-on-question-by-anderson-brunel-modolon-comunicacao-local-atraves-de-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi postar algo simples após observar os comentários. Agora pude ter mais confiança sobre qual solução apresentar.

Eu penso sempre em soluções simples então vamos a uma alternativa realmente simples.

A questão aqui é como fazer o servidor "online" enviar dados para o servidor numa intranet.

Se focarmos nessa lógica sem observar o real cenário, vamos imaginar soluções inadequadas e confusas. Observando bem o cenário, o servidor na internet não precisa enviar os dados para as impressoras. Isso pode ser feito pelo tablet que está na página do servidor.

Achei que ficaria confuso explicar sem ilustrações, por isso fiz alguns rabiscos.

Primeiro vamos dar uma geral no cenário para melhor entendimento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O cliente faz um pedido e o garçom dá entrada no sistema pelo tablet.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando completar, o servidor online retorna uma página com um formulário oculto com campos tipo hidden.

O action do form apontará para o endereço do servidor local na intranet.

Nesse exemplo, está sendo pedido uma pizza. Então no formulário será especificado o parâmetro "printer" com o valor "pizza".

```
<form action="http://192.168.1.50" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="printer" value="pizza">
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="os dados que deseja enviar para a impressora imprimir">
</form>
```

Note que o servidor online não tem acesso algum a rede local do restaurante, pois essa rede não está aberta na internet.

Essa comunicação é possível porque o processo se dá em client-side, pelo brower do dispositivo cliente, o navegador do tablet.

Tecnicamente, é o tablet que está enviando a requisição e não o servidor online.

Pode também implementar uma função que envie o formulário por ajax caso queira algo mais "refinado", mas não fará diferença alguma no resultado final.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O formulário oculto pode ter um botão para o garçom enviar manualmente ou pode ser disparado automaticamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Daqui para frente acredito que não preciso entrar em detalhes porque são coisas muito simples.

Se o servidor for Windows, pode usar as funções `printer` do PHP
http://php.net/manual/fa/function.printer-open.php

Pode implementar também a comunicação com as impressoras usando sockets http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php

Simples assim, sem estruturas mirabolantes e custos monstruosos. É eficiente e simples de manter.

<sub>*Desculpe pelos desenhos exdrúxulos.</sub>

Comment: Exatamente o tipo se solução que eu buscava. Valeu!!

Answer (score 2):

Se a comunicação com o servidor for esporádica, e/ou iniciada pelo usuário (por exemplo, ao clicar em um botão de Atualizar), você deve implementar a busca dos dados no cliente usando AJAX, nesse caso não é uma comunicação sentido SERVIDOR <- CLIENTE, mas sim CLIENTE -> SERVIDOR, porém, com AJAX, ela acontece sem recarregar a página e a interface continua totalmente responsiva.

Caso precise de comunicação em tempo-real, por exemplo, para implementar um chat, ou um jogo multiusuário, ou uma implementação de uma interface colaborativa, onde usuários de computadores diferentes participam numa mesma tela (e isso é orquestrado pelo servidor), então o melhor é utilizar as novas funcionalidades para comunicação de baixa latência entre servidor/cliente.

**Arquitetura para aplicação com servidor local e remoto**

Para ter uma aplicação que tenha funções locais centralizadas (impressão) e também um servidor remoto que guarde as informações históricas, os cadastros de produtos, etc. o ideal é realmente dividir em camadas o aplicativo. Abaixo uma arquitetura proposta baseada em Android, servidor local ASP.NET Web.API 2/MVC 5, e servidor remoto usando API APPs do Azure com banco de dados SQL Azure (você pode modificar essa arquitetura completamente para usar Amazon AWS, ou até mesmo um servidor provisionado por você).

[image: Arquitetura proposta com Azure]

Nessa arquitetura todos os componentes da rede local compartilham o mesmo WiFi (ou rede ethernet para o caso do servidor local que pode estar ao lado do roteador). O servidor expõe um webserver (no caso IIS da Microsoft) com uma API desenvolvida em ASP.NET Web.APi 2. Esse servidor, por sua vez, se comunica com o servidor remoto implementando no Microsoft Azure que expõe uma API através do serviço de API APPS do Azure (que facilita demais gerenciar e criar APIs). Para podermos compartilhar a maior quantidade possível de código entre servidor remoto, local e app android, a app android pode ser programada em Xamarin em C# no Visual Studio, permitindo reutilizar classes de modelo de negócio e transporte de dados, bem como clientes das APIs, já que tudo será escrito em C#. O Xamarin cria aplicativos nativos para Android (iOS e Windows Phone), compartilhando mais de 95% do código entre eles. Os aplicativos tem a mesma performance dos escritos em Java no Android e em Objective-C no iOS, pois são compilados nativamente ao final do processo, ou dinamicamente na máquina virtual do android.

**Comunicação de aplicação WEB com servidores**

A implementação de comunicação web com servidores pode ser feita de diversas formas. Abaixo as mais comuns.

**A opção *de facto* é WebSockets.**

Um tutorial em português: https://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Para PHP, uma biblioteca: http://socketo.me/

Documentação oficial: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/WebSockets

**Notas**

Contudo, mesmo um cliente de chat, ou uma aplicação colaborativa podem funcionar com AJAX puro e operações de "polling" (o cliente consulta o servidor, por exemplo, à cada 30s para ver se há novos dados). Era assim que essa coisas eram feitas no passado recente.

Implementar comunicação em tempo-real não é algo simples. Normalmente os iniciantes cometem tantos erros que acabam desistindo e uma implementação em "polling" com AJAX pode ser mais simples para iniciar.

Contudo uma aplicação com baixa latência de atualização de dados é uma maravilha para o usuário final, como também gera muito orgulho em quem a construiu.

Existem também opções aos WebSockets, e camadas de abstração em cima deles também (que podem decair graciosamente para polling ou outro mecanismo mais simples em browsers que não suportem websockets, por exemplo).

Comment: A comunicação seria esporádica após o usuário clicar em um botão na aplicação e ela passaria os dados para o servidor local. No caso fazendo em AJAX, seria necessário utilizar algo do tipo no-ip, ou apenas fixando o ip já seria o suficiente? A minha dúvida seria em fazer a aplicação on-line encontrar o servidor local para passar os dados.

Comment: @AndersonBrunelModolon o que você quer dizer como servidor local? A sua aplicação já não está conectada a um servidor, de onde ela é "servida" e lá roda sua lógica? Você quer que ela se comunique com um outro servidor à mais? Que servidor é esse? Explique melhor seu cenário na pergunta! Se for só para mandar os dados por AJAX para o servidor é trivial, vou até colocar um exemplo:

Comment: Sim, é apenas enviar os dados via AJAX da aplicação web para o servidor local. A minha dúvida é se basta apenas o servidor estar na mesma rede do dispositivo que acessa a aplicação (vamos supor, com ip fixo) ou tenho que fazer algo mais seja do lado AJAX ou do servidor. O servidor é PHP puro que estará preparado para receber os dados enviados via AJAX.

Comment: @AndersonBrunelModolon atualizei a resposta com uma arquitetura que considero mais robusta (lembrando que detalhes da arquitetura podem e devem ser adaptados para o seu caso e seu rol de conhecimentos)

Comment: Tem gente que fez confusão com a minha pergunta. Focalizei apenas na comunicação ao fato de já existir um sistema em PHP praticamente finalizado, mas sem estas novas funcionalidades pois surgiram de forma recente a idéia. Fica complicado utilizar .NET a este contexto.

Comment: @AndersonBrunelModolon aconselho veementemente que use android no app do garçom e não uma WebView que mostra um site mobile feito em PHP. Isso não vai funcionar para o tipo de problema. Agora, todo o resto da arquitetura que sugeri pode ser substituído por PHP. Basta que você publique uma API REST em PHP (não implemente uma API de outra forma que não REST!). Um framework indicado pra isso seria http://www.slimframework.com/ Você pode reutilizar o código PHP atual em boa parte da API, como também o banco de dados existente, etc.

Comment: No caso você está dizendo para o servidor local colocar algo do tipo um "no-ip" afim de que fique acessível via web e trabalho a comunicação entre ele o tablet com arquitetura REST?  (Tablet AJAX => SERVIDOR REST com no-ip)

Comment: @AndersonBrunelModolon não, nada disso. Seu servidor local fica local, na rede WiFi local (conforme expliquei no texto da resposta). Seu app android se comunica com esse servidor através do IP local dele (que deve ser fixo, ou via DNS se seu roteador permitir isso). No app você deve ter uma área administrativa para indicar o IP do servidor local. Você então consome essa API localmente indicando o IP do servidor local. É muito simples, não há necessidade de ser acessado remotamente! Ou esse app vai rodar FORA da rede local do restaurante?

Comment: O aplicativo ficará hospedado on-line e a comunicação com os Tablets é via internet Wi-Fi que tem no estabelecimento. No caso basta eu fixar o IP do servidor local (dentro do estabelecimento), gravando ele no Tablet e acessando via AJAX? O sistema por ser on-line tem uma área administrativa/relatórios que é possivel acessar fora sim, mas a parte dos Tablet's e comunicação com o servidor somente dentro do estabelecimento.

Comment: @AndersonBrunelModolon se você criar uma aplicação web dentro dos tablets e não uma aplicação android, então você acessará os dados via AJAX acessando o servidor local. Somente o servidor local é que acessa o servidor remoto (para buscar novos produtos, novos preços, etc.). Se você usar uma aplicação ANDROID acessará o servidor local usando uma biblioteca para acesso a APIs REST, como Retrofit (https://square.github.io/retrofit/). Mesmo que vc use um website no android com AJAX, programe o servidor local para expor uma API REST, mesmo que seja em PHP: http://www.slimframework.com/

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que a principal diferença entre o servidor de hospedagem e o seu servidor local é o fato de que um está online e o outro não, devido principalmente ao seu modem agindo como firewall, podemos dizer que a solução básica seria:

- Realizar o redirecionamento de portas no seu modem para que seja possível acessar o seu servidor local pela internet (ver [Port Forwarding](https://portforward.com/d-link/di-624m/));
- Configurar sua aplicação online (hospedada) para consumir um serviço ou url através da biblioteca [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

  ```
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://seuip:8080/teste.php");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  var_dump($response);
  ```

Mas atenção.. imagino que isso não passe de uma brincadeira. Pois não veja razão nenhuma nesse mundo que justifique expor seu servidor local na rede.

Comment: Na verdade é apenas um  servidor de impressão, e o fato de querer fazer via AJAX seria ao fato de não expor, pois não se sabe se futuramente virão outras necessidades com este servidor. Mas a principio a sua ideia é válida sim.